# Product of primitive Dirichlet characters , modulo co-prime positive integers, is primitive?

Tags: number-theory, abelian-groups, characters

If $\chi_1 , \chi _2 : \mathbb Z \to \mathbb C$ are two primitive Dirichlet characters modulo $n_1 , n_2$ respectively such that gcd$(n_1,n_2)=1$ , then is it true that the Dirichlet character $\chi_1 \chi_2$ , modulo $n_1n_2$ , is also primitive  ? ( I can show the converse i.e. if product of two Dirichlet characters , modulo co-prime natural numbers , is primitive then so are each of them )

Please help . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

A $\chi$ modulo $N$ is non-primitive iff $\chi(n) = \psi(n) 1_{(n,k)=1}$ for some $\psi$ modulo $N/k$ where $k | N$. Do you think it can happen if $\chi = \chi_1\chi_2$ two primitive characters modulo coprime $N_1,N_2$ ?

More generally any Dirichlet character $\chi_N$ modulo $N$ decomposes uniquely as $\chi_N = \prod_{p^e \| N}  \chi_{p^e}$, which follows from the Chinese remainder theorem $(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^\times \simeq\prod_{p^e \| N} (\mathbb{Z}/p^e\mathbb{Z})^\times$ ie. for every $a$ there is a $n \bmod N$ such that $n \equiv a \bmod p_1^{e_1}$ and $n\equiv 1 \bmod p_j^{e_j}$ for $j \ne 1$ so that $\chi_{p_1^{e_1}}(a)=\chi_N(n)$

Comment: I can't prove that $\chi$ must be primitive if $\chi_1$ and $\chi_2$ are.

Comment: @Mr.209 It is obvious once you know the **definition** of primitive

Comment: Well, it's not obvious for me...

Comment: @Mr.209 Because you didn't write precisely what you want to show. Define $\chi$ in term of $\chi_1,\chi_2$, define "non-primitive", use what I said to define $\chi_1,\chi_2$ in term of $\chi$.

Comment: Clearly, we could write $\chi(n) = \chi_1(n) \cdot \chi_2(n) = \psi(n) \cdot 1_{(n, ab) = 1}(n)$ where $\psi$ is a character mod $d$, a divisor of $ab$.

Comment: @Mr.209 Not if the $\chi_1,\chi_2$ are primitive, because the map $\chi_1,\chi_2 \to \chi_1\chi_2$ is inversible.

Comment: Yes,  but that were only a problem if $\psi(n)$ was a character mod $a$ (like $\chi_1$), but it isn't. The map doesn't care if the two functions come from different domains.

Comment: $ab$ has a prime factorization.. Or look at $(k,a),(k,b)$ where $k$ is ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68789/discussion-between-mr-209-and-reuns).

Comment: @Mr.209 I made it clear in the answer above : $\chi= \prod_{p^e\| N} \chi_{p^e}$ and it is primitive iff none of the $\chi_{p^e} = 1_{(n,p)=1}$. Once this is clear, all you need is counting the number of characters $\bmod p^e$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the unique non-principal $\chi$ character modulo $4$. Is it primitive? What about its square $\chi^2$?

Comment: Sorry , I forgot to add that $\chi _i$ 's are Dirichlet characters modulo co-prime integers ...